# In magento 2 How to get all customer data without using object manager?

Tags: magento2, customer, customer-data

In customer module need to show all customer data whatever I want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) Use \Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Customer\CollectionFactory class to get customer collection

```
    <?php

protected $_customerFactory;

public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Customer\CollectionFactory $customerFactory
    ...
) {
    ...
    $this->_customerFactory = $customerFactory;
    ...
}

/**
 * Get customer collection
 */
public function getCustomerCollection()
{
    return $this->_customerFactory->create();
}
```

Then you can call:

```
  <?php

$customerCollection = $this->getCustomerCollection();

foreach ($customerCollection as $customer) {
    echo $customer->getEmail();
}
```

2) Use \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface class to get customer by customerId or customer email

```
   protected $_customerRepositoryInterface;

public function __construct(
    ....
    \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepositoryInterface,
    ....
) {
    ....
    $this->_customerRepositoryInterface = $customerRepositoryInterface;
}

/**
 * Get Customer by id
 */
public function getCustomer($customerId)
{   
    return $this->_customerRepositoryInterface->getById($customerId);
}

/**
 * Get Customer by email
 */
public function getCustomerByEmail($customerEmail)
{   
    return $this->_customerRepositoryInterface->get($customerEmail);
}
```

Comment: If It's Useful solution please upvote and right them.

Comment: hey Tushar this code get last  5 order to home page ?

Comment: I have get last 5 orders all imformation on home page what to do? without using object manager ?

Comment: Tushar ple expain me step by step i am a begginer so 
I have get last 5 orders all imformation on home page what to do? without using object manager ?

Comment: protected $OrderFactory;
public function __construct(\Magento\Sales\Model\OrderFactory $OrderFactory
) {$this->OrderFactory = $OrderFactory;}

Comment: public function orderCollection()
{
 $orderCollection = $this->OrderFactory->create()->getCollection();
 $orderCollection->getSelect()->limit(5);
    foreach ($orderCollection as $key => $orderID) {
        $order = $this->OrderFactory->create()->load($orderID->getId());
        $orderItems = $order->getAllItems();
        foreach ($orderItems as $item) {
            $product_name = $item->getName();
            $product_id = $item->getProductId();
            echo $productName . "||" . $product_id;
        }
    }
}

Comment: Please this question ask in your account

Comment: ok please see my question

Comment: Please give your question url.

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/272574/i-am-a-begginer-in-magento-so-i-have-get-last-5-orders-all-imformation-on-home-p