# Magento 2 : Get last five order information using DI on homepage?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.3

I want to get last 5 order information on home page.

> Question : How to get last five order collection information on homepage?

**NOTE :** Avoid giving answers using object manager.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

Create a **block** and add the below code to it,

Block path be like

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Block/Orders.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Block;
class Orders extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
public function __construct(
 \Magento\Sales\Model\OrderFactory $orderFactory
) {

   $this->orderFactory = $orderFactory;

}
public function getCollection()
{
   $collection = $this->orderFactory->create()->getCollection()->addFieldToSelect('*')->setOrder('created_at','desc');
   $collection->setPageSize(5);
   return $collection;
}
}
```

then in your phtml you can call like below

```
 $order_collection = $block->getCollection();
 foreach($order_collection as $items){
 $items->getId(); 
 $items->getName();  // like this you can get any data from sales_order table information
 }
```

you can call any of the phtml in the home page to get this information.

To call a phtml only on home page follow the below steps

create a **cms_index_index.xml** in the below path

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout/cms_index_index.xml

then add the below code to it

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
   <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template"  name="sales_total" template="Vendor_Module::order_total.phtml">
        </block>
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
</page>
```

**Vendor_Module** - this should you namespace_modulename

And also place **order_total.phtml** in the below path

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/templates/order_total.phtml

Hope this helps.

Comment: hello Prathap I have recevice orders but I have used block folder and in this one file create and call phtml this way I have get any solution for this?

Comment: updated for block, you can simple follow the above instruction and hope that will work if not please let me know

Comment: Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException): Element 'block', attribute 'class': [facet 'pattern'] The value 'Wds\Coreoverride\Block\orders' is not accepted by the pattern '[A-Z][_a-zA-Z\d]*(\\[A-Z][_a-zA-Z\d]*)*'.
Line: 713Prathap Gunasekaran  I am facing this error

Answer (score 0):

Please Use below code

```
    <?php
        namespace Vendor\Module\Block;

        class order extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
        {    
        protected $OrderFactory;

            public function __construct(
                ...
                \Magento\Sales\Model\OrderFactory $OrderFactory
                ...
            ) {
                ...
                $this->OrderFactory = $OrderFactory;
                ...
            }

            public function orderCollection()
            {
                $orderCollection = $this->OrderFactory->create()->getCollection();
                $orderCollection->getSelect()->limit(5);
                return $orderCollection;

            }
        }
```

Comment: <?php
 
 $orderCollection = $this->orderCollection();
 
 ?>
 in phtml file this way call